# How to declare COM-visible default indexed properties in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, com

how do you declare a default indexed property in VB.NET such that it is callable from VBScript?

I have tried this using

```
<DispId(0)> _
Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal idx As Integer) As ...
```

but VBScript returns the error message

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
Error Code 800A01C2

This error does not occur if I expose a normal property (non-indexed) from VB.NET.

Here is a sample:

'Class1.vb:

```
  Public Class Class1
    Public ReadOnly Property Dogs() As Dogs
        Get
            Return New Dogs()
        End Get
    End Property
  End Class
```

'Dogs.vb:

```
  Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

  Public Class Dogs
    <DispId(0)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal idx As Integer) As Dog
        Get
            Return New Dog
        End Get
    End Property
  End Class
```

'Dog.vb:

```
  Public Class Dog
    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return "Fido"
        End Get
    End Property
  End Class
```

VBScript:

```
  Set obj = CreateObject("FmuComTest.Class1")

  MsgBox obj.Dogs.Item(0).Name   ' this works

  MsgBox obj.Dogs(0).Name        ' error message
```

Accessing the default indexed property Dogs.Item(idx) causes the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MSDN blog post may shed some light on the matter. It seems VBScript & COM are picky about how defaults are invoked.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/08/30/458051.aspx

Comment: Obviously, the CLR does not implement IDispatch::Invoke() in the same way as native COM (as described in the above MSDN blog). Microsoft Support suggested to add an optional indexer to all properties that return a collection; this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional VB, I think the ID used for the default property was -1. I have no idea if this makes any sense in terms of a DispId, though.

Comment: According to the header files, -1 is DISPID_UNKNOWN, whereas 0 is DISPID_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the property as a `Default` property.  You also need to omit the `DispId` attribute.  For instance:

```
Public Class Dogs
    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As Dog
        Get
            Return New Dog()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The compiler will automatically assign DISPID 0 to the default property, so explicitly stating it in the attribute is unnecessary.